# When is a ring extension satisfying Going-Up and incomparability property , an integral extension?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-extensions

For an extension of commutative rings $R \subseteq S$ , the extension is said to satisfy

Going Up (GU) property if for every chain of prime ideals $P \subseteq P_0$  of $R$ with $P=Q \cap R$ for some prime ideal $Q$ of $S$, there is a prime ideal $Q_0$ of $S$ such that $Q \subseteq Q_0$ and $P_0=Q_0\cap R$

and is said to satisfy Incomparability (NC) if for any two prime ideals $Q_1,Q_2$ of $S$ , $Q_1 \subseteq Q_2$ and $Q_1\cap R=Q_2\cap R \implies Q_1 =Q_2$ .

Now it is known that , any integral extension satisfies GU and NC property.

My question is : If a ring extension $R \subseteq S$ satisfies GU and NC property, then is it true that the extension is integral ?

If this is not true in general, can some extra condition on $R$ and/or on $S$ force the extension to be integral ?

Comment: Clearly, any field extension satisfies GU and NC.

Comment: @MooS : Let us assume that not both $R$, $S$ are fields

Comment: Then let $k \subset K$ be a non-algebraic field extension and consider $k[t]/(t^2) \subset K[t]/(t^2)$.

Comment: @MooS : Ah indeed ... what if $R,S$ are integral domains ?

Comment: Take $k[[t]] \subset K[[t]]$. Not allowing all known counter examples is not a reasonable assumption, I guess.

Comment: Things become more interesting, if $R$ and $S$ are at least two-dimensional, because in this case, there are infinitely many prime ideals. But I do not know about reasonable assumptions to force the extension to be integral other than saying it should be integral.